# is functional requirement is necessaryfor wireframing

Tags: wireframe, ux-designer

Is there need of functional requirement for creating wireframe?
or low level requirement is enough for wireframe design.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of **DEPENDS** type of question which depends on how and to whom you are explaining your product.

But on the same phase if you are asking in general, then **of course, yes** it is mandatory to do **Requirement Gathering**(Business, User, System requirements) to have a better user experience.

### Additional

I recommend you to read Jesse James Garrett's [The Elements of User Experience](http://www.amazon.com/Jesse-James-Garrett/e/B001IGNGXI).
He has explained the five stages of UX in a very good manner.

[image: The Elements of User Experience]
You can see that **Scope** is the second where we focus on the requirements and **Skeleton** is the fourth stage where the wireframing part comes.

Happy UX.